# Retrieve upper triangular elements of a matrix and order them by off-diagonal order

Tags: r, matrix, vector, diagonal

I have a matrix (dimension can be large) and want to retrieve all upper triangular elements then order them by off-diagonal order. For example, given `A = matrix(1:25, 5, 5)`, the output `res` is

```
res = c( c(6,12,18,24), c(11,17,23), c(16,22), c(21) )
## i.e, res = c(offdiag_vect_1, offdiag_vect_2, offdiag_vect_3, offdiag_vect_4)
```

I know the upper triangular elements can be retrieved through `A[upper.tri(A, diag=FALSE)]`, but not sure how to re-order them in a `c(offdiag_vect_1, offdiag_vect_2, ..., offdiag_vect_(n-1))` manner in an efficient way.

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing from [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49433217/1320535), you may use

```
split(A, col(A) - row(A))
```

to get a list of all diagonals. Then adding `tail` allows to get only the upper ones, and `unlist` gives a vector:

```
unlist(tail(split(A, col(A) - row(A)), ncol(A) - 1))
# 11 12 13 14 21 22 23 31 32  4 
#  6 12 18 24 11 17 23 16 22 21
```

Adding `unname` yields gets rid off the names:

```
unname(unlist(tail(split(A, col(A) - row(A)), ncol(A) - 1)))
# [1]  6 12 18 24 11 17 23 16 22 21
```

For a large matrix it should help not to compute the irrelevant diagonals. Then

```
unname(unlist(split(A[upper.tri(A)], (col(A) - row(A))[upper.tri(A)])))
# [1]  6 12 18 24 11 17 23 16 22 21
```